# "Provide you with something" vs "Provide you something"?

Tags: prepositions

I have a sentence that reads: "To provide you the best possible service..."

I'm being asked to add the word *with* so that it reads "To provide you with the best possible service..."  Is there a rule for whether or not I add the word *with* or is it a preference and the sentence works either way?

Comment: If neither of the indicated questions helps, please edit this question explaining exactly what is still unclear.